# Put a semi-colon (or someonething else) in front of multiple lines in Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++

Say I've the following lines in Notepad++:

```
1234
1234
1234
```

Suppose I want to put a semicolon in front of every line to get something like:

```
; 1234 
; 1234 
; 1234
```

, i.e. indent by a space and write a semi-colon.

I already know how to indent multiple lines with TAB, but this is causing me trouble. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a try with:

Click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find what: `^`
Replace with: `;` (semicolon and space)

Make sure that `Regular expression` is checked.
Then click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

You could also do:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and move  the mouse from first to last line before the first character (mode column) then enter the characters you want; they will be inserted at the beginig of all selected lines.

Comment: It's worth noting that the "regular expression" search mode is needed here

Comment: So one cannot do it by simply keyboard shortcuts ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: I've added another way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ has a [column editing mode](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/editing/), also known as rectangular selection. Hold down the ALT key then drag (with the left mouse button pressed) over a block of text. That selects a rectangular area of the text. With a rectangle selected, typed characters will be entered on every line of the rectangle.

With care one can select a zero-width rectangle at the start of the lines of text.  So, for the case in this question, select a zero-width rectangle at the start of the relevant lines, then type the semi-colon and space, or the other characters, that are wanted.